# How do I do calculation in CircuitLab? How do I provide +Vcc and -Vcc to the OpAmp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, circuitlab

Here is my simple circuit. I would like to test whether the output is correct as per manual calculation. According to manual calculation, Gain=3.1, Vo=10.54V.

My question are:

- How do I do that calculation?
- Is my way to do +Vcc and -Vc connection correct? Which both should be connected to +12V and -12V respectively.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkkebh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Your power connection is incorrect. There are many examples on the internet.

Comment: Try it yourself $$V_O = Vg \frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} \times \left(1 +\frac{R_F}{R_S}\right)$$

Comment: I am asking, **How do I do calculation in *CircuitLab***.

Comment: @G36, your formula is correct. Using that formula will get V Thavenin (VTh) = 3.4V, and the gain is (1+63k/30k)=3.1. The Vo=VTh*gain=10.54V. But I want to verify that calculation using CircuitLab as I want to calculate another problem.

Comment: I do not understand, Simply left-click on "simulate this circuit" under your circuit. And click on the bottom "Simulate" -->"Run DC Solver"  And then point a click on the node you want to "display the voltage".   https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfs6f.png

Answer (score 2):

> According to manual calculation, Gain = 3.1, Vo = 
>    10.54 V.

Nope. You're feeding 4 V in so a gain of 3.1 would give an output of 12.4 V. Something wrong somewhere.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUd6rq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Redrawn schematic to show the circuit blocks.*

> How do I do that calculation?

Break down the circuit into its functional blocks.

1. The input signal is 4 V and fixed. That's easy.
2. Next you have a potential divider. (This is the part missing in your overall gain calculation.) The output of that is given by the ratiometric division $$ V_O = \frac {R1}{R1 + R2} Vg $$.
3. This is followed by, what should now be obvious, a non-inverting amplifier stage. The output of this is given by $$ V_O = ( 1 + \frac {R_f}{R_s} ) V_I $$
4. Next is the load. This doesn't affect the output provided we don't overload it. 27 kΩ will be fine.
5. The power supply becomes important because an op-amp output can't go above the positive supply voltage and can't go below the negative supply voltage. In most cases it can't get within a couple of volts of either supply rail so we'll come back to this later.

The output of your circuit will be the product of all the stages that affect the signal; the divider and the non-inverting amplifier.
$$ V_O = V_g \frac {R1}{R1 + R2}( 1 + \frac {R_f}{R_s} ) $$

> Is my way to do +Vcc and -Vc connection correct? Which both should be connected to +12V and -12V respectively.

Now we come back to the power supply.

- Your input signal of 4 V is driving the output to 10.5 V which is only 1.5 V from positive supply. You need to check the op-amp datasheet to see if it is capable of getting that close to positive supply. Some are. Some aren't.
- The power supply limits the maximum input signal. If V<sub>g</sub> > 4 V then you need to raise the 12 V to a higher voltage.
- As V<sub>g</sub> is decreased towards 0 V the op-amp may reach the lower output limit. If this is a problem you need to choose an op-amp that can output to negative rail or use a negative supply rail.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjoVei.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Split rail powered version.*

[image]

*Figure 3. Internals of the ancient 741 opamp. Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Internal_circuitry_of_741-type_op-amp).*

Most opamps will have an output arrangement similar to the push-pull arrangement of the old 741. Others will have FET transistors rather than BJTs. In either case if the top transistor (red oval) is turned on the output will be pulled to positive rail. If the bottom transistor (green oval) is turned on the output will be pulled to negative rail. How close they get depends on the exact output configuration and the driving circuitry.

---

Answering the questions in the title:

> How do I do calculation in CircuitLab?

For this example you just run the DC solver. This is simplest if you attach a NODE to your input, V<sub>g</sub>, and your output, R<sub>o</sub>. Simulate | DC Solver | Click each of the nodes to add them in | Run.

> How do I provide +Vcc and -Vcc to the op-amp?

See my Figure 2.

Comment: I got the circuit and that calculation from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2F8SIRQsgKI): You may jump to minute 4:53. And that the thing I want to verify. But is it using 741.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not see any image due to blocked/filtered by service provider.

Comment: Sorry, why do I need to watch a video? Are you saying you can't see the images in my answer?

Comment: As you claimed that the calculation is wrong. That calculation is no mine.

Comment: The presenter already accounted for the attenuator (voltage divider) and at that point in the video is looking at the amplifier stage. I looked at the whole lot. You need to look at my answer using a different provider or via some sort of proxy.

Comment: Above, below the question's body, @g36 put a formula. That's the formula used by the presenter to calculate the gain and the Voutput at Ro (27k). Using that formula we get Gain=3.1, Vo=10.54V.

Comment: But my concern actually is how do I use CircuitLab to calculate as I want to verify my calculation. And also, how do I connect +Vcc and -Vcc. So, this is like asking tutorial.

Comment: @Transistor the guy in the video states that the gain is given by Vo/V+ (instead of Vo/Vg) and using that you will get a gain of 3.1

Comment: @Jan: Correct, but I answered the question at the top of this page which didn't mention a video or Vo/Vg. If the OP works through my answer s/he should get 3.1 for step 3.

Comment: @Transistor true but the op has not read your or my answer correctly about that gain

Comment: "*But my concern actually is how do I use CircuitLab to calculate ...*" See the update and G36's instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have the following circuit (and we assume an ideal model of an OPAMP):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYmTWG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using KCL, we can write:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_4=\text{I}_-+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_x=\text{I}_++\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{o}=\text{I}_4+\text{I}_5
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

Using KVL, we can write:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_x=\frac{\text{V}_x-\text{V}_+}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_--0}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_+-0}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_\text{o}-\text{V}_-}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\frac{\text{V}_\text{o}-0}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

***Notice***: in the ideal OPAMP circuit we assume that \$\text{I}_+=\text{I}_-=0\$ and \$\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-\$.

Now, the gain is defined by:

$$\text{G}:=\frac{\text{V}_\text{o}}{\text{V}_x}\tag3$$

We can find an expression for the output voltage \$\text{V}_\text{o}\$, by solving the systems of equations:

$$\text{V}_\text{o}=\frac{\text{V}_x\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3\right)}\tag4$$

So, we get:

$$\text{G}=\frac{1}{\text{V}_x}\cdot\frac{\text{V}_x\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3\right)}=\frac{\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3\right)}\tag5$$

> In your case we get:
>
> $$\text{G}=\frac{68000\cdot\left(30000+63000\right)}{30000\cdot\left(12000+68000\right)}=\frac{527}{200}=2.635\tag6$$

---

Solving it, in general, gives (notice that \$\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-=\text{V}_\text{p}\$:

[image]

In your case (using your values):

[image]

> I checked my solution using LTspice and I got it right.

Comment: Wow! Hard work!

Comment: @Transistor Thanks,  just a few minutes of thinking.

Comment: You need to verify your calculation and the formula you use. Check again. There are mistakes there.

Comment: @AirCraftLover I did using LTspice. Look at the bottem of my answer

Comment: See the answer from @g36 below the question's body. It is the correct formula to calculate. Moreover, my concern in my question is something like asking tutorial **How do I do calculation using CircuitLab** rather than asking how to calculate.

Comment: The calculation I got from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2F8SIRQsgKI).

Comment: @AirCraftLover the guy in the video does the same thing as I did, but I think my method is more general (almost always useable). And for the simulation use LTspice it's a good tool for this kind of excercises

Comment: I am not sure yours is more general or not, but for sure, it is incorrect. By pointing in the node, I can see the Vo. Unfortunately the gain is not shown. But however, as the output voltage on the Ro (=27k) is correctly shown, the gain must be correct.

Comment: @AirCraftLover if you look at the video you mention, the guy states that the gain is given by Vo/V+ and then you will get a gain of 3.1. But that is a strange way of talking about the gain. Don't say that my answer is incorrect, you are wrong about that it is rude to say that you definitely need to go back to school because I'm 100% right.

Comment: Just do whatever you think right if you want to go wrong further. Even the CircuitLab calculate correctly as in the video. One thing, gain is not calculate from the input to the output. Gain calculate with formula (1+Rf/Rs) for this Non-Inverting amplifier. And Gain=-Rf/Rs for inverting. As I said, the comment above by @g36 is the correct one to calculate, the thing he put inside bracket. Vo is the output we need to calculate, not the known parameter.

Comment: @AirCraftLover no the formula is wrong, gain is calculated from output to input so